# Having trouble retrieving integer from .properties

Tags: java, spring

I keep getting the java.lang.NumberFormatException: null error when I am trying to use an integer that I set in application.properties.

This is my application.properties

```
my.prop.for.func=25
```

This is how I retrieved the value from the .properties file and converted it to an integer to use in a function later on.

```
@Value("${my.prop.for.func}")
private String myPropForFuncStr;
private int myPropForFunc = Integer.parseInt(myPropForFuncStr);
```

I tried other ways of converting the property to an integer such as 
@Value("#{new int ('${my.prop.for.func}')}") but they gave other errors and this seemed like the easiest way.

I am probably getting the NumberFormatException: Null error because myPropForFuncStr is null. I have always retrieved values from .properties file like this so why is it messing up right now?. If that isn't the problem, what else could give the NumberFormatException: Null error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring initializes classes with their annotated attributes after instantiation. That means, the call "Integer.parseInt" will be called before spring can load the properties, because the class already has been initialized.

You have several options to solve this:

1. Write an void init method with the @PostConstruct annotation. In this method, all spring related informations are already loaded.
2. Write an getter, that always parses to integer on call in runtime
3. I think spring can also handle:

   @Value("${my.prop.for.func}")
   private Integer myPropForFuncInt;

Comment: Thank you. I had tried option 3 but with int instead of integer. After I changed it to integer, it started working fine.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly Spring framework already handles the autoboxing for you. Which means that you can directly add the annotation to the int variable.

```
@Value("${my.prop.for.func}")
private Integer myPropForFunc; // Note that this needs to be an object and not a primitive data type.
```

Now, coming to your issue, you may want to check if your class has been annotated with the `@PropertySource` annotation. If you are using Spring boot to initialize your application, then it should have automatically read your `application.properties` file and injected these properties to the fields appropriately. But if you are not, then you will need to annotate your class with `@PropertySource` annotation. Even if you were using Spring boot, your setup would not have worked since the `@Value` will be evaluated after the bean has been successfully initialized, but you are initializing the value of the `myPropForFunc` at the field itself.

Here is an example which shows the usage of the annotation.
https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/

Comment: Thanks. I did already try adding that annotation but it gave me an error. After I changed int to integer, it started working fine.

Comment: Updated the answer based on your finding.

Answer (score 0):

`myPropForFuncStr` is not initiated at the time you try to convert it to int.
I would suggest to add `@Value` directly on `myPropForFunc`

```
@Value("${my.prop.for.func}")
private int myPropForFunc = Integer.parseInt(myPropForFuncStr);
```